# GET API request to github repo

Tags: api, get, github-api

So, I have a get request:

```
https://api.github.com/users/exampleName/repos
```

This returns a list of json objects which are all the public repos this user has.

What if I want to get one of his specific repo by its full_name like

```
https://api.github.com/users/exampleName/repos/?full_name=exampleFull_name.
```

I tried this but it is not working.

I am not sure how to retrieve a specific Json object from a list in a api call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the repo name, the URL for the request is:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/[user]/[repo]
```

Where `[user]` is the repo owner's GitHub username, and `[repo]` is the repo name.

[GitHub Docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get-a-repository)

Example:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the username and repo directly. You can just generate the url:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{reponame}
```

If you don't know the repo name, you'll have to perform multiple API queries.

First you need to get the list of public repos with:

```
https://api.github.com/users/exampleName/repos
```

Then you need to loop through all the repos and find the name that matches the one you want. For example you want the repo named `ExampleRepository`. Once you get the repo object that matches what you want. You can get the `url` for that repo.

```
[
  {
    ...
    "name": "ExampleRepository",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ExampleName/ExampleRepository",
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: [You don't need multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62722098/12860895)

Comment: I guess we cant directly get that specific repo in a api call right.

Comment: If you know the username and reponame you can go directly to the repo.